# Weird ItemsPanelTemplate issue (possible Silverlight bug?)

Tags: silverlight, itemspanel

I'm trying to create a **horizontally oriented stack panel** that contains a **vertically oriented stack panel of items**. Here's my code.

First the **XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
>   

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SquareTemplate">
        <Border Margin="2" Background="Blue" Width="80" Height="80"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="VerticallyTiledItemTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SquareTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>          
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VerticallyTiledItemTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now the code-behind...

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>> _myCollection = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>>();

        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>> MyCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return _myCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                _myCollection = value;
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = MyCollection;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                var innerCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    innerCollection.Add(new object());
                }

                _myCollection.Add(innerCollection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see **two columns of three blue squares**, but instead I see **one column of six squares**

I can't see anything about the code that jumps out at me as blatantly wrong...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the root `ItemsControl` into a `StackPanel`, when you actually want to put the items in the `ItemsControl` into the `StackPanel`. Change to this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VerticallyTiledItemTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```